# Cache Grafana plugin locally

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, amazon-eks

We have a strict egress rules and not allowing the domain from which Grafana pulls the plugins.
Wondering if someone cached or injected plugins when the Grafana pod is coming up in k8s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GrafanaLabs' recommended deployment comes with configured [volumeMounts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/).

```
...
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
              name: grafana-pv
...
```

You can try and put plugin files there.
This is, however, the worst possible way to install plugins. Not to mention, when container restarts, you will have to reinstall all plugins again.

[Recommended](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/docker/#install-official-and-community-grafana-plugins) way to install plugins is to either specify then at container start

```
docker run -d \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  --name=grafana \
  -e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-clock-panel,grafana-simple-json-datasource" \
  grafana/grafana
```

*or* from [other sources](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/docker/#install-plugins-from-other-sources)

```
docker run -d \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  --name=grafana \
  -e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=http://plugin-domain.com/my-custom-plugin.zip;custom-plugin" \
  grafana/grafana
```

*or* [build a custom docker image with plugins pre-installed](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/docker/#build-and-run-a-docker-image-with-pre-installed-plugins).

Considering you situation, last solution may be the best.
You can build images in the netowork where plugin directory is allowed, if that doesn't break your company's policy.

Comment: We have already built an image and installed the plugin at build time but your answer is basically 120% correct , thx for the time